# How to avoid Sass variable name repeat in _variables.scss?

Tags: css, variables, sass

I have _variables.scss which is structured like this following [BEM naming conventions](http://getbem.com/naming/).

```
$slot-width: 100px;
$slot-height: 10px;
$slot-title-width: 80px;
$slot-title-height: 10px;
```

I'm repeating variable names `$slot-`. Is there a way to do something like:

```
$slot {
  &-width: 100px;
  &-height: 10px;
  &-title {
    &-width: 80px;
    &-height: 10px;
  }
}
```

And it compiles to the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Sass Maps](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps):

```
$slot: (
  "width": 100px,
  "height": 10px,
  "title": (
    "width": 80px,
    "height": 10px
  )
);
```

Additionally, here's a good article on [getting values out of deep Sass maps](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/).

However, it may be easier to continue using regular variables with hyphens, as you already have.

Comment: Do you mean it may be easier to just repeat variable names rather than using Sass Maps?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu Yeah. But try it out and see if you like it. It's a tradeoff between efficient declaration of variables vs efficient use of variables later when applying them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) :

```
$slot: (
    "width": 100px,
    "height": 10px
);

.some_bem__selector { width: map-get($slot, width); }
```